# Automatically map MySQL bit fields to bool properties

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

Consider that I got several models that store some flags using MySQL's bit field. 
I know that it can easily be converted into bool by doing the follow:

```
$myBoolFlag = (ord($model->myFlag) == 1) ? true : false;
```

I'm looking for some way to make it map to a boolean property automatically.

Please someone tell me that there is an better way than creating setters and getters for every bit field in my project. I bet that Phalcon has some magic configuration in the DB service or something like this...

Comment: do you need those flags to really be bools internaly? `1 == true` works just fine in PHP, even though 1 is an integer. Or are you doing `1 === true`, which would be false.

Comment: I'm okay with int too. The main problem is the bit fields being parsed as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up by following the Nikolao's approach and implemented a base class for my models that can parse bit fields into more practical values. However, I designed it to not override  the default mapping behavior. Something like that:

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public function explicitDataTypes()
    {
        //TODO: Suport relational data
        $numargs = func_num_args();

        if($numargs)
        {
            foreach (func_get_args() as $arg)
            {
                if(isset($this->$arg)) $this->$arg = $this->explicitDataType($arg)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value)
            {
                if($key[0] != '_') $this->$key = $this->explicitDataType($key)
            }
        }
    }

    public function explicitDataType($propertyName)
    {
        $value = $this->$propertyName;

        if(is_numeric($value))
        {   
            $locale = localeconv();
            $separatorCount = substr_count($value, $locale['decimal_point']);

            if($separatorCount == 0) $value = (int)$value;
            elseif($separatorCount == 1) $value = (float)$value;
        }
        elseif(strlen($value) == 1 && ord($value) <= 1) $value = ord($value) == 1;

        return $value;
    }
}
```

#### Examples

```
class User extends BaseModel
{
    protected $password;

    public function afterFetch()
    {
        //Explicit data type for specific fields (e.g. var_dump($user->activated); //bool(true))
        $this->explicitDataTypes('activated', 'deleted');
    }
}

class Location extends BaseModel
{
    public function afterFetch()
    {
        //Explicit data type for specific all fields (e.g. var_dump($location->distance); //float(12.3)
        $this->explicitDataTypes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I have dealt with a similar issue is to create map arrays in each model and work with those. More specifically:

```
<?php
/**
 * Model.php
 *
 * Model
 *
 * @author      Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
 * @since       2012-12-12
 * @category    Library
 *
 */

namespace NDN;

use \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault as PhDi;
use \Phalcon\Mvc\Model as PhModel;

class Model extends PhModel
{
    private $meta = [];

    /**
     * Some init stuff
     */
    public function initialize()
    {

        // Disable literals
        $this->setup(['phqlLiterals' => false]);
    }

    /**
     * Universal method caller. This checks the available methods based on
     * the fields in the meta array and returns the relevant results
     *
     * @author  Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
     * @since   2015-02-15
     *
     * @param   string      $function
     * @param   array|null  $arguments
     *
     * @return  mixed|void
     * @throws  \Exception
     */
    public function __call($function, $arguments = null)
    {
        // $function is something like getId, setId, getName etc.
        $metaFunction = substr($function, 3);
        $field        = $this->getMetaFunctionToField($metaFunction);

        if ($field) {

            $prefix    = substr($function, 0, 3);
            $fieldName = $field['field'];

            switch ($prefix) {
                case 'get':

                    /**
                     * Data manipulation here if needed
                     */
                    $value = $this->getField($fieldName);
                    $value = $this->metaFieldValidate($field, $value);

                    return $value;
                    break;

                case 'set':

                    /**
                     * Data manipulation here
                     */
                    $value = $this->metaFieldValidate($field, $arguments);

                    $this->setField($field, $value);
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            throw new \Exception('Function does not exist');
        }
    }

    /**
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * PROTECTED METHODS
     * -------------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    /**
     * Gets a field from the model with the correct prefix
     *
     * @param $name
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getField($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;

    }

    /**
     * Sets a field in the model
     *
     * @author  Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
     * @since   2014-02-15
     *
     * @param   string  $field
     * @param   mixed   $value
     */
    protected function setField($field, $value)
    {
        $this->$field = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the DI container
     *
     * @author  Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
     * @since   2014-02-22
     *
     * @return  mixed
     */
    public function getDI()
    {
        return PhDi::getDefault();
    }

    /**
     * Accesses the internal array map to provide the field name from a function
     *
     * @author  Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
     * @since   2014-02-27
     *
     * @param   string  $prefix     The prefix of the table
     * @param   string  $function   The aliased function
     *
     * @return  string  The field name (i.e. tnt_id)
     *          bool    False if not found
     */
    public function getMetaFunctionToField($function)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($function, $this->meta)) {
            return $this->meta[$function];
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Validates a setter value based on each field's type
     *
     * @author  Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
     * @since   2014-02-17
     *
     * @param   string  $field  The field to check
     * @param   mixed   $value  The value of the field
     *
     * @return bool|int|string
     */
    protected function metaFieldValidate($field, $value)
    {
        // Find the validator
        $validator = $field['validator'];

        switch ($validator)
        {
            case 'int':
                $return = intval($value);
                break;
            case 'bit':
                $return = (ord($value) == 1) ? true : false;
                break;
            case 'bool':
                $return = (bool) $value;
                break;
            case 'decimal':
                $return = (float) $value;
                break;
            case 'string':
                $return = (string) $value;
                break;
            case 'datetime':
                /**
                 * @todo check datetime validator
                 */
                $return = (string) $value;
                break;
            default:
                $return = $value;
                break;
        }

        return $return;
    }

}
```

A sample `User` model looks like this

```
<?php
/**
 * User.php
 *
 * User
 *
 * @author      Nikos Dimopoulos <nikos@niden.net>
 * @since       2014-03-08
 * @category    Models
 *
 */

namespace NDN;

use \NDN\Model as NDNModel;

class Model extends NDNModel
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        /**
         * This is where I will set the field map
         * 
         * The key of the array is the function name without 
         * the prefix. So for instance if you want getName()
         * to return the user.name you use Name as the key
         */
        $this->data = [
            'Id' => [
                'field'     => 'user_id',
                'validator' => 'int',
            ],
            'Name' => [
                'field'     => 'user_name',
                'validator' => 'int',
            ],
            'IsMarried' => [
                'field'     => 'user_is_married',
                'validator' => 'bit',
            ]
        ];

        parent::initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO that's a lot of boilerplate code, I'll try do to something similar that doesn't require manually map the properties on each model, as I said, I got many of them. Anyway thanks for the quick answer, loving Phalcon so far and I hope to contribute to the project soon...

Comment: Agreed it does require effort in creating the model and further on in its maintenance later on. However, this does what you need and it doesn't come with any overhead that you might incur by using DESCRIBE or other functions to find what each field is before transforming its contents to whatever you need.